# How is the definition of linear independence for infinite sets useful?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given this fact: 
"an infinite set is linearly independent iff all of its finite subsets are linearly independent", 
how can this help us determine whether an infinite set is linearly independent if some of finite subsets could be arbitrarily large?

Comment: Well, you need a definition even if there can be situations which are difficult to analyze.  Is there a specific situation that concerns you?

Comment: As a concrete example, consider polynomials over $\mathbb R$ and let $S$ be the set $\{1,x,\cdots, x^n,\cdots\}$.  It's clear, isn't it?, that every finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb R$, hence $S$ is.

Answer (score 0):

I see now that it is useful as if we have an infinite set, and then we take a subset of arbitrary size and show that this set of arbitrary size is linearly independent then all subsets are linearly independent and hence the set itself is linearly independent